# How to get asymptotic approximations for complex summations like $S_n = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}^2 {2(n-i)\choose (n-i)}$

Tags: probability, asymptotics, random-walk

I asked a question about this summation (in the process of proving that a 3-d random walk is transient):

$$S_n = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}^2 {2(n-i)\choose (n-i)}$$

in this post: [Summation coming about in the process of solving a 3d random walk $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}^2 {2(n-i)\choose (n-i)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4814423/summation-coming-about-in-the-process-of-solving-a-3d-random-walk-sum-limits/4814461#4814461).

In the answer, Claude mentioned [this sequence](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C15%2C93%2C639%2C4653%2C35169&language=english&go=Search) where it is buried the following approximation:

$$S_n \sim  \frac{3^{2 n+\frac{3}{2}}}{4 \pi  n}$$

This totally solved my problem and the desired result immediately popped out.

But since I was meaning it to be a complete end to end proof, the question remains how to come up with the approximation.

Comment: This is Vaclav Kotesovec's talent !

Comment: Using the Stirling' approximation (it can be shown that it is applicable here) and Laplace' method, is straightforward to show that
$$S_n(s) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}^s {2(n-i)\choose (n-i)}\sim\frac{(2\pi n)^{-s/2}}{\sqrt{2s}}(1+4^{1/s})^{s(n+1)-1/2}\,\,\text{at}\,\,n\to\infty$$

Comment: In the OEIS they provide a generating function for the sequence. You can apply singularity analysis to the gf to obtain the desired asymptotics. I can recommend this excellent book on the subject: https://ac.cs.princeton.edu/home/

Answer (score 2):

To save you the calculation of the hypergeometric function, take list of numbers given in $OEIS$, take their logarithms and use a linear regression , the prdictors being $n$ and $\log(n)$
$$\log(S_n)=a+ b\, n + c\, \log(n)$$ With an $R^2=0.99999984$, the resultsa are
$$\begin{array}{l|lll}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Std Error} &
   \text{Confidence Interval} \\
\hline
 a & -1.06943 & 0.00713 & \{-1.08448,-1.05438\} \\
 b & +2.18941 & 0.00100 & \{+2.18730,+2.19153\} \\
 c & -0.89294 & 0.00729 & \{-0.90832,-0.87756\} \\
\end{array}$$

Now, search in the $ISC$ your prefered numbers for
$$1.06943239808173345453079354467\cdots$$
$$2.18941203440648792537395963290\cdots$$
$$0.89293825070137998724963846596\cdots$$

Answer (score 1):

*I prefer to add a separate answer.*

With a bit of heuristics plus the help of the $ISC$ for one of the constants

$$A_n=\log\Bigg(\,
   _3F_2\left(-n,-n,-n;1,\frac{1}{2}-n;\frac{1}{4}\right)\Bigg)$$ is
$$A_n \sim -\frac{15 (2 \gamma -1)}{2+3 e^{\gamma }}+\Bigg(\frac{\pi }{4}+\frac{1}{100} \left(\Omega+e^{\frac{1}{e}+\frac{1}{\pi
   }}\right)\Bigg)\,n-\frac 12 \log(n)$$

For $n=456$, the above gives $e^A=1.3455\times 10^{159}$ while the value of the hypergeometric function is $1.3511\times 10^{159}$.

If the three parameter linear regression was made for $10\leq n \leq 10^4$ (step of $10$), the adjusted correlation coefficient would be $R^2=0.9999999999999943$.

So
$$S_n \sim \binom{2 n}{n}e^{A_n}$$