# Expected number of times a 3-d random walk will return to the origin

Tags: probability, random-walk

It's a famous result that a symmetric random walk in 1-d comes back to the origin an infinite number of times, so does a symmetric random walk in 2-d. But a symmetric random walk in 3-d comes back to the origin only a finite number of times. For the 1-d and 2-d cases, this is show in the book Introduction to Probability models by Sheldon Ross, example 4.18.

We know that for the 3-d case, the probability of coming back to the origin is 37% (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolyasRandomWalkConstants.html).

This begs the question, what is the expected number of times a 3-d random walk will come back to the origin?

---

My approach: take the summation in the question: [Summation coming about in the process of solving a 3d random walk $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}^2 {2(n-i)\choose (n-i)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4814423/summation-coming-about-in-the-process-of-solving-a-3d-random-walk-sum-limits) and numerically calculate it for a large number of terms. I'm wondering if there is a better way or a purely mathematical solution.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something, but isn't that just the expectation value of the geometric distribution with $p=0.34$ from your link? meaning, isn't the expectation just $\frac{1}{p}$?